# How do I import an array of data into separate rows in a hive table?

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, create-table, hive-serde

I am trying to import data in the following format into a hive table

```
[
    {
      "identifier" : "id#1",
      "dataA" : "dataA#1"
    },
    {
      "identifier" : "id#2",
      "dataA" : "dataA#2"
    }
]
```

I have multiple files like this and I want each {} to form one row in the table. This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE final_table(
    identifier STRING,
    dataA STRING
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION "s3://bucket/path_in_bucket/"
```

This is not creating a single row for each {} though. I have also tried

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE final_table(
    rows ARRAY< STRUCT<
    identifier: STRING,
    dataA: STRING
    >>
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION "s3://bucket/path_in_bucket/"
```

but this is not work either. Is there some way of specifying that the input as an array with each record being an item in the array to the hive query? Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need

**Method 1: Adding name to the array**

Data

```
{"data":[{"identifier" : "id#1","dataA" : "dataA#1"},{"identifier" : "id#2","dataA" : "dataA#2"}]}
```

SQL

```
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ramesh_test (
  data array<
    struct<
      identifier:STRING, 
      dataA:STRING
    >
  >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 'my_location';

SELECT rows.identifier,
       rows.dataA
  FROM ramesh_test d
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(d.data) d1 AS rows  ;
```

Output

[image]

**Method 2 - No Changes to the data**

Data

```
[{"identifier":"id#1","dataA":"dataA#1"},{"identifier":"id#2","dataA":"dataA#2"}]
```

SQL

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ramesh_raw_json (
  json STRING
)
LOCATION 'my_location';

SELECT get_json_object (exp.json_object, '$.identifier') AS Identifier,
       get_json_object (exp.json_object, '$.dataA') AS Identifier
  FROM ( SELECT json_object
           FROM ramesh_raw_json a
           LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (split(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(a.json,'\\}\\,\\{','\\}\\;\\{'),'\\[|\\]',''), '\\;')) json_exploded AS json_object ) exp;
```

Output

[image]

Comment: This requires modifying to {"data":<the data that I currently have>}. I want to find out if there's anyway I can do this without having to modify the existing data.

Comment: @shrewquest - If you didn't want to name your array object then I think you will have to explode the array and use get_json_object to get the values. In my experience that's messy and slow in term of performance. My suggestion would be to create a temp table to concat the name to the array object.  You could either do that in a UNIX script or in Hive itself using a a temp table.

Comment: @shrewquest - Updated the answer with method 2 which doesn't require changes to your data. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

JSON records in data files must appear one per line, an empty line would produce a NULL record.

This json should work

{       "identifier" : "id#1",       "dataA" : "dataA#1"     },
{       "identifier" : "id#2",       "dataA" : "dataA#2"     }

Comment: The json I put up is formatted for readability. If you mean get rid of [ ] then I have 11672 files, is there some option to specify that each file is an array is what I'm asking

Comment: Can you provide a sample expected output for better understanding

Comment: expected output is a hive table with each item in the array as one row in the table

Comment: I had the same question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969182/extract-json-in-array-in-aws-athena now 2 years later. Too bad none of the suggested solutions here created the results you wanted, so that I could have done the same.