# extract json in array in AWS Athena

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have sent logs from kubernetes to an S3 bucket and want to query it using Athena

The log looks like this

```
[{      "date":1589895855.077230,
      "log":"192.168.85.35 - - [19/May/2020:13:44:15 +0000] \"GET /healthz HTTP/1.1\" 200 3284 \"-\" \"ELB-HealthChecker/2.0\" \"-\"",
      "stream":"stdout",
      "time":"2020-05-19T13:44:15.077230187Z",
      "kubernetes":{
         "pod_name":"myapp-deployment-cd984ffb-kjfbm",
         "namespace_name":"master",
         "pod_id":"eace0175-99cd-11ea-95e4-0aee746ae5d6",
         "labels":{
            "app":"myapp",
            "pod-template-hash":"cd984ffb"
          },
         "annotations":{
            "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict":"false",
            "kubernetes.io/psp":"eks.privileged"
          },
         "host":"ip-1-1-1-1.eu-north-1.compute.internal",
         "container_name":"myapp",
         "docker_id":"cb2cda1ed46c5f09d15090fc3f654b1de35970001e366923287cfbd4a4abf4a1"
      }
},
{      "date":1589995860.077230,
      "log":"192.168.1.40 - - [20/May/2020:17:31:00 +0000] \"GET /healthz HTTP/1.1\" 200 3284 \"-\" \"ELB-HealthChecker/2.0\" \"-\"",
      "stream":"stdout",
      "time":"2020-05-20T17:31:00.077230187Z",
      "kubernetes":{
         "pod_name":"myapp-deployment-cd984ffb-kjfbm",
         "namespace_name":"master",
         "pod_id":"eace0175-99cd-11ea-95e4-0aee746ae5d6",
         "labels":{
            "app":"myapp",
            "pod-template-hash":"cd984ffb"
          },
         "annotations":{
            "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict":"false",
            "kubernetes.io/psp":"eks.privileged"
          },
         "host":"ip-1-1-1-1.eu-north-1.compute.internal",
         "container_name":"myapp",
         "docker_id":"cb2cda1ed46c5f09d15090fc3f654b1de35970001e366923287cfbd4a4abf4a1"
      }
},]
```

So an array with json object in it basically.

I am using an CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE query in Athena to create the table.
What I have tried is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS athenadb.mytable (
                   `data` string
                 )
                 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
                 LOCATION 's3://mybucket/testlog'
                 TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

This only read the first item in the array into the table, unless I specified more rows such as

data1 string

data2 string

data3 string

However since I don't know how many items is in the array I need something more dynamic.

Then I tried this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS athenadb.mytable (
                   `data` string
                 )
                 LOCATION 's3://mybucket/testlog'
                 TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Now I get the entire log (both entries) in one row in the table.

From here I have tried to use UNNEST but I get errors that "cannot unnest type: varchar"

What would be the simplest way to get each {} into its own row in the table? Maybe done from the CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE without needing any extra queries afterwards?

Edit:

Tried this as well now

```
SELECT data
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(data) AS array)) AS data2
```

But I get "Unknown type: array"

I found a similar question here: [How do I import an array of data into separate rows in a hive table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522270/how-do-i-import-an-array-of-data-into-separate-rows-in-a-hive-table)

But there didn't seem to be any suggested solution that created the wanted result.

Comment: Try `CAST(json_parse(data) AS array(json))`.

Comment: Using query `SELECT data FROM mytable CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(data) AS array(json)) AS data2`
gives error
`line 3:57: mismatched input 'as' expecting {'.', ',', ')', '[', 'at', 'or', 'and', 'in', 'not', 'between', 'like', 'is', '=', neq, '<', '<=', '>', '>=', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '||'} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 609bf5ad-5d87-4eb3-b50d-ddfd9add6024)`

Comment: This query got me closer. `SELECT data FROM mytable CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(data) AS ARRAY<json>))`
The array has two json entries and I get two rows now, but each row contains all two jsons instead of one each

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 7):

Combine [`unnest`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) with [casting `json` to `array(json)`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#cast-from-json):

```
SELECT data, e
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(data) AS array(json))) t(e)
```

Note: `array<json>` is a legacy version of `array(json)` type definition. The latter is SQL standard compliant.