# Invalid cast argument when querying JSON object in an array in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto

I have a very large json file that consists of a single json object in an array that I'm trying to query via AWS Athena.

```
[  {"reporting_entity_name": "Aetna Life Insurance Company", 
    "reporting_entity_type": "Third Party Administrator",
    "last_updated_on":"2022-09-05",
    "providers": [...],
    "in-network": [...]} ]
```

Here's the table definition I created in Athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aetna.adobe_temp_5 (
plan string
)
LOCATION 's3://insurance-transparency-data/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data' = 'false');
```

I tried using adapting the query suggested in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969182/extract-json-in-array-in-aws-athena) and got the following error

```
SELECT plan, e FROM adobe_temp_5 CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(plan) AS array(json))) t(e)

INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to array(json). Expected a json array, but got { {"reporting_entity_name": "Aetna Life Insurance Company", "reporting_entity_type": "Third Party Administrator"...
```

I'm new to presto and ultimately want to be able to query the data that is nested in this JSON object, but I am having a terrible time just accessing the object to query the basics.

Comment: As additional context, I originally tried to create the table using JSON SerDe but every time I queried it it gave me a JSON error that it was expecting "}" at the end of the file. I assumed the problem was that my json was nested in [], hence the current strategy.

Comment: can you please post result of `select plan from adobe_temp_5`?

Comment: @GuruStron It is underneath the Select statement above: INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to array(json). Expected a json array, but got { {"reporting_entity_name": "Aetna Life Insurance Company", "reporting_entity_type": "Third Party Administrator"...

Comment: @dsal1951 I just tried your sample data and queries. Everything ran fine.Can you share output of select plan from adobe_temp_5 ?