# How to stop loading full JSON object into single field in AWS Athena

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, struct, amazon-athena, create-table

I am attempting to load JSON data from S3 into a table in Athena.

My JSON data looks like this;

```
[{"a":"a_value", "b":"b_value", "my_data":{"c":"c_value", "d":1, "e":2}},
{"a":"a_value", "b":"b_value", "my_data":{"c":"c_value", "d":2, "e":3}},
{"a":"a_value", "b":"b_value", "my_data":{"c":"c_value", "d":3, "e":4}},
{"a":"a_value", "b":"b_value", "my_data":{"c":"c_value", "d":4, "e":5}},
{"a":"a_value", "b":"b_value", "my_data":{"c":"c_value", "d":5, "e":6}}]
```

My statement to create the table looks like this;

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_db`.`my_table`(
    `a` string,
    `b` string,
    `my_data` STRUCT< 
        `c`: STRING,
        `d`: INT, 
        `e`: INT>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'ignore.malformed.json' = 'FALSE',
  'dots.in.keys' = 'FALSE',
  'case.insensitive' = 'TRUE',
  'mapping' = 'TRUE'
)
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://myjsondata/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification' = 'json');
```

I get;

- Three columns, a, b, my_data
- One row.
- Column a contains {"a":"a_value", "b":"b_value", "my_data":{"c":"c_value", "d":1, "e":2}
- Column b contains {"a":"a_value", "b":"b_value", "my_data":{"c":"c_value", "d":2, "e":3}
- Column my_data contains {"c":null, "d":null, "e":null}

What I actually want is

| a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a_value | b_value | c_value | 1 | 2 |
| a_value | b_value | c_value | 2 | 3 |
| a_value | b_value | c_value | 3 | 4 |
| a_value | b_value | c_value | 4 | 5 |
| a_value | b_value | c_value | 5 | 6 |

Could someone help me see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar question

[extract json in array in AWS Athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969182/extract-json-in-array-in-aws-athena)

And if your data format is in this format then you don't have to write complex query as in [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969182/extract-json-in-array-in-aws-athena)

```
{ "id" : 50, "name":"John" }
{ "id" : 51, "name":"Jane" }
{ "id" : 53, "name":"Jill" }
```

Follow [this link](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/error-json-athena) to more about the format of data